# Is there documentation for turbopower's OnGuard anywhere?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, turbopower, onguard

Er...is there documentation for turbopower's OnGuard anywhere?

Finally got the source code to turn itself into components on the pallete (D2009) and can run the examples but I don't know what most of the components do or which I need.

There used to be documentation when it was a commercial product. Does it still exist?

Howard

Ah, I'd been looking for two days and eventually found the documentation five minutes after posting this message. To save anyone else the trouble they are here 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tponguard/files/tponguard_docs/1.13/

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is still [available on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tponguard/files/), along with the source code.

**Update**: Most of the TurboPower components are being maintained as part of [TurboPack](https://github.com/TurboPack), a collection of open source tools being kept up to date by Roman Kassebaum. The most recent versions of the source code and documentation for OnGuard are on [GitHub](https://github.com/TurboPack-Tokyo/OnGuard-VCL).

Answer (score 3):

For two examples on how to use the OnGuard library look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349165/licensing-with-onguard).

The two approaches there are roughly equivalent, [Runner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349165/licensing-with-onguard/4352640#4352640) creates the OnGuard components at runtime, while [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349165/licensing-with-onguard/4352709#4352709) uses the procedural OnGuard API and has slightly less overhead as a result.

There is a third approach of dropping the components on a form directly rather than creating them at runtime. There's nothing particularly wrong with doing this, I've just found it unnecessary and not really saving anything more than a line or two of code.